# How can I create a vertical dumbbell plot (waterfall graph or lollipop plot with endings)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to create a waterfall graph for a medical study (or vertical dumbbell plot, or lollipop plot with start and endpoints). The best-looking version seems to be created with geom_dumbbell function, however, I couldn't find how to turn the graph so lines aligned vertically, not horizontally.

Can you help?

```
wfx <- ggplot(data, aes(y=obs, x=low, xend=high)) +

geom_dumbbell(size=0.75, color="black", size_x=2, colour_x = "red", size_xend=2,colour_xend = "blue") + 
  ggpubr::fill_palette(palette = "lancet") +
  ggpubr::theme_pubr()

wfx + facet_grid(cols = vars(trt))
```

[The output graph of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Rqh.png)

Comment: Do you need `+ coord_flip()` ?

Comment: This is absolutely what I needed. Thanks